# @Mock RestTemplate not returning expected value

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, spring-resttemplate

I am creating unit test for my service class:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class SsaOpeningService {

    @Autowired
    private MockDataInitializer mockDataInitializer;

    @Qualifier("restHttpsTemplateClient")
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${acc-opening-casa.open-ssa}")
    private String openSSAaccountUrl;

    public CompletableFuture<AccountData> openSsa(
            ApplicationDto items,
            HttpHeaders headers,
            BigInteger cifNo) {
        
        log.info("Initializing headers");
        HeaderRequest headerRequest = new HeaderRequest();
        HttpHeaders header =  headerRequest.initHeader(headers);

        CurrentAcctReqBody request = CurrentAcctReqBody.builder()
                .cifNo(cifNo)
                .currencyType(SGD_CURRENCY)
                .acName1(items.getApplicationData().getPersonalDetail().getName())
                .productType(SSA_PRODUCT_CODE)
                .noOfAccountHolders(BigInteger.ONE)
                .accountType(ACC_TYPE)
                .transactionRefNo(mockDataInitializer.randomIntInString(9))
                .build();

        log.info("Setting up entity for calling SSA opening.....");
        HttpEntity<CurrentAcctReqBody> entity = new HttpEntity<>(request, header);

        CurrentAcctResBody result = null;
        try {
            result = restTemplate
                    .postForObject(openSSAaccountUrl, entity, CurrentAcctResBody.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info(e.getMessage());
        }

         System.out.println(14527);
         System.out.println(result);

        if(result !=null && result.getError()==null) {
            AccountData accountData = AccountData.builder().build();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(result.getRbkAccountDetail(), accountData);
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(accountData);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class SsaOpeningServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks private SsaOpeningService ssaOpeningService;

    @Autowired private MockDataInitializer dataInitializer;

    @Mock private MockDataInitializer mockDataInitializer;

    private static HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    private static HeaderRequest ekycHeaderRequest = new HeaderRequest();

    @BeforeAll
    public static void init() {
        headers = ekycHeaderRequest.initHeader();
    }

    @Qualifier("restHttpsTemplateClient")
    @Mock private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void createSsa() throws IOException {

        CurrentAcctResBody result = JSONUtils
                .getObjectFromJson(DCResourceLoader.getResourceAsString("casa/ssa-res.json"), CurrentAcctResBody.class);

        ApplicationDto items = ApplicationDto.builder().build();
        Application application = dataInitializer.initialize();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(application, items);

        when(restTemplate.postForObject(
                any(String.class),
                eq(HttpEntity.class),
                eq(CurrentAcctResBody.class)))
            .thenReturn(result);

         System.out.println(1452);
         System.out.println(result);

        when(mockDataInitializer.randomIntInString(any(Integer.class)))
                .thenReturn(dataInitializer.randomIntInString(9));

        assertThat(ssaOpeningService.openSsa(items, headers, any(BigInteger.class))).isNull();
    }
}
```

I have mocked my RestTemplate to return me the result I want. Problem is, it is not giving me the expected result. I have printed the result in both test class and service class. But in the service class it is always giving me null. I tried to give the most generic parameter when mocking but still doesnt work. The rest is working fine when running unit test EXCEPT for this part. Need assist on this. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class SsaOpeningServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private SsaOpeningService ssaOpeningService;

    @Mock
    private MockDataInitializer mockDataInitializer;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void createSsa() throws IOException {

        // some code
  
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForObject(
                nullable(String.class),
                any(HttpEntity.class),
                eq(CurrentAcctResBody.class)))
            .thenReturn(result);

        // some code
    }

}
```